# Sequelize - include column and getting string instead of object

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an problem which I can't resolve in any way, I'm including user -> avatar models in PostTip model and when I want to add column with OBJECT avatar (id + src) I can't make it.
Name, email works because I'm pointing to single value not object.
Where is the problem?

```
PostTip.findAndCountAll({
      attributes: {
        include: [
        **  [db.sequelize.col(`"user"->"avatar"`), "avatar"],**
          [db.sequelize.col(`"user"."name"`), "name"],
          [db.sequelize.col(`"user"."email"`), "email"],
        ],
      },
      offset: offset,
      limit: limit,
      order: order,
      where: {
        postId: req.params.id,
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: "user",
          attributes: [],
          include: [{ model: AwsAvatar, as: "avatar" }],
        },
      ],
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, 2));
      const data = getPagingData(result.rows, result.count, query.page, limit);
      return res.send(data);
    });
  };
```

and results are:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 1,
    "tipAmount": 100,
    "createdAt": "2023-01-11T22:10:26.440Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-11T22:10:26.440Z",
   ** "avatar": "(1,1,https://dh7ieyc6s2dxm.cloudfront.net/avatars/1673514260216_0e69489d-fc95-4ed8-b615-2a76ce43385.webp,\"2023-01-12 09:04:21.223+00\",\"2023-01-12 09:04:21.223+00\")",**
    "name": "Test User",
    "email": "test@test"
  }
```

Im expecting to have output like that:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 1,
    "tipAmount": 100,
    "createdAt": "2023-01-11T22:10:26.440Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-11T22:10:26.440Z",
 ** "avatar": {
       "id": 1,
       "userId": 1,
       "src": "https://dh7ieyc6s2dxm.cloudfront.net/avatars/1673514260216_0e69489d-fc95-4ed8-b615-2a76ce5ff385.webp",
       "createdAt": "2023-01-12T09:04:21.223Z",
       "updatedAt": "2023-01-12T09:04:21.223Z"

    },**
    "name": "Test User",
    "email": "test@test"
  }
```

User model:

```
import { Optional } from "sequelize";
import {
  Column,
  Table,
  Model,
  DataType,
  ForeignKey,
  BelongsTo,
  Default,
  HasMany,
  HasOne,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import UserRole from "../../enums/user-role.enum";
import AwsAvatar from "../aws/aws-avatar.model";
import PostComment from "../post/post-comment.model";
import PostLike from "../post/post-like.model";
import PostTip from "../post/post-tip.model";
import Card from "./card.model";
import Role from "./role.model";

interface UserAttributes {
  id: number;
  avatar: AwsAvatar;
  name: string;
  setName: string;
  description: string;
  hashtag: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  isVip: boolean;
  lastUsedCardNum: string;
  sendNotifications: boolean;
  cards: Card[];
}

interface UserCreationAttributes
  extends Optional<
    UserAttributes,
    | "id"
    | "avatar"
    | "setName"
    | "description"
    | "hashtag"
    | "cards"
    | "isVip"
    | "lastUsedCardNum"
    | "sendNotifications"
  > {}

@Table({ tableName: "users" })
export default class User extends Model<
  UserAttributes,
  UserCreationAttributes
> {
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public name!: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public setName!: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public email!: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public password!: string;

  @HasOne(() => AwsAvatar)
  public avatar!: AwsAvatar;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public description!: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public hashtag!: string;

  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  public isVip!: boolean;

  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  public subscriptionActive!: boolean;

  @Column(DataType.DATE)
  public subscriptionExpireDate!: Date;

  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  public emailConfirmed!: boolean;

  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  public invalidEmail!: boolean;

  @Column
  public buyedContent!: string;

  @Default(0)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  public wallet!: number;

  @Default(0)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  public spent!: number;

  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  public isMessageReaded!: boolean;

  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  public sendNotifications!: boolean;

  //
  @Column
  public messageContainerDto!: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public lastUsedCardNum!: string;

  @HasMany(() => Card)
  public cards!: Card[];

  @ForeignKey(() => Role)
  @Default(UserRole.User)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  public roleId!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Role)
  public role!: Role;

  @HasMany(() => PostTip)
  public tips!: PostTip[];

  @HasMany(() => PostComment)
  public comments!: PostComment[];

  @HasMany(() => PostLike)
  public likes!: PostLike[];
}
```

Avatar model:

```
import { Optional } from "sequelize";
import {
  Column,
  Table,
  Model,
  DataType,
  ForeignKey,
  BelongsTo,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import User from "../user/user.model";

interface AwsAvatarAttributes {
  id: number;
  src: string;
}

interface AwsAvatarCreationAttributes
  extends Optional<AwsAvatarAttributes, "id"> {}

@Table({ tableName: "aws_avatars" })
export default class AwsAvatar extends Model<
  AwsAvatarAttributes,
  AwsAvatarCreationAttributes
> {
  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  public userId!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
  public user!: User;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public src!: string;
}
```

I know it can be done smth like that, but cmon, I believe that there is any way to join avatar table and not for each loop every time when fetching data:

```
private getPostTips = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const query = req.query as unknown as { name: string } & PaginationDto;

    const { limit, offset } = getPagination(query.page, query.size);

    const condition = query.name
      ? {
          name: {
            [Op.iLike]: "%" + query.name + "%",
          },
        }
      : {};

    const order: any[string] = [[query.sort, query.order]];

    PostTip.findAndCountAll({
      raw: true,
      nest: true,
      attributes: {
        include: [
          [db.sequelize.col(`"user"."name"`), "name"],
          [db.sequelize.col(`"user"."email"`), "email"],
        ],
      },
      offset: offset,
      limit: limit,
      order: order,
      where: { postId: req.params.id },
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: "user",
          attributes: [],
          where: condition,
          include: [{ model: AwsAvatar, as: "avatar" }],
        },
      ],
    }).then((result) => {
      **const sorted: any[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        let item = {
          avatar: result.rows[i].user.avatar,
          ...result.rows[i],
          user: undefined,
        };
        sorted.push(item);
      }**
      const data = getPagingData(sorted, result.count, query.page, limit);
      return res.send(data);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can you show model definitions along with associations?

Comment: I've added them to original post. Feel free to ask about anything. Really appreciate your willings to help me! :)

Comment: You can add a direct association from `PostTip` to `Avatar` and include it right next to `User` in the query `include` option